# How can I highlight selected UICollectionView cells? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, and the user is able to select multiple cells. It's a bit difficult to keep track of which cells have been selected, so I need some way to go about highlighting/creating a border when the cell is tapped.

Code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    addToList.append(objectsArray[indexPath.row])

    return true

}
```

Comment: just use the didselect and diddeselect delegate methods :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you can use border change on `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` override event like the below code and assign new settings on the cell.

Swift 3.x:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    addToList.append(objectsArray[indexPath.row])
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}
```

Comment: Gray color just appear after you selected. When selecting, it has no effect.

Comment: how should i deselect when i select the same index at another time i.e remove the border color of selected index if the index already has border color.

Comment: @HariNarayanan use func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {} for that

Comment: @BenjaGarrido, your edit was not building, please test your changes before submitting edits.

Answer (score 20):

**SWIFT**

Add this code to your UICollectionViewCell subclass:

```
 override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet{
        if self.isSelected {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { // for animation effect
                 self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 115/255, green: 190/255, blue: 170/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
        else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { // for animation effect
                 self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 60/255, green: 63/255, blue: 73/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will set the color of a single selected cell, and remove the selected color from any previous selected cells. I've added a smooth animation to it. I think it's nice, but it's optional.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 18):

Here is my solution, and I'm sure it works.

My solution includes 3 highlight effects, `UICollectionCell`'s `selectedBackgroundView`, `cell.contentView.backgroundColor`, or your your own `specialHighlightedArea`; just feel free to choose the one you need, and feel free to add more effects as your App's Designer requires.

How to use? Just inherit `BaseCollectionViewCell`. If needed, configure in cell's `init` or `collectionView`'s delegate methods.

If you don't need highlight effect, just find a method named '[shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618070-collectionview)' in [UICollectionViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate) and return `false` or just set `cell.shouldTintBackgroundWhenSelected = false`.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(rgb: Int, alpha: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0, green: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0xFF) / 255.0, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
/// same with UITableViewCell's selected backgroundColor
private let cellHighlightedColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xD8D8D8) 

class BaseCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var shouldTintBackgroundWhenSelected = true // You can change default value
    var specialHighlightedArea: UIView?

    // make lightgray background show immediately（on touch）
    // (使灰背景在手指触到 cell 时立即出现)
    override var isHighlighted: Bool { 
        willSet {
            onSelected(newValue)
        }
    }
    // keep lightGray background from selected until unselected 
    // (保留灰背景直至取消选中)
    override var isSelected: Bool { 
        willSet {
            onSelected(newValue)
        }
    }
    func onSelected(_ newValue: Bool) {
        // selectedBackgroundView is defined by UICollectionViewCell
        guard selectedBackgroundView == nil else { return }
        if shouldTintBackgroundWhenSelected {
            contentView.backgroundColor = newValue ? cellHighlightedColor : UIColor.clear
        }
        if let sa = specialHighlightedArea {
            sa.backgroundColor = newValue ? UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4) : UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

to reload current cell, or

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

to reload all cells in `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` set your border or background color if the cell is marked as checked (you may need a new array for checked cells with preferably indexPaths.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a customized collcetionViewCell, and override:

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if self.isHighlighted {
                print("yes")
                // Your customized animation or add a overlay view
            } else {
                print("no")
                // Your customized animation or remove overlay view
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can create similar result like the highlight effect on UITableViewCell.

**Without subclassing:**

If you don't want to create your own collectionViewCell. you can use the delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

You can do the same thing with it.

Comment: Now after changing the view or removing overlay from cell how will i reload the collection view from the cell to see the changes? Because i cannot see changes in my view and the print function is working properly in the console.

Answer (score 4):

For multiple selection of cell, you can do it as follow:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    if let currentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? QuestionnaireCollectionViewCell {

        // Your selection logic, you can change it according to your requirement
       if currentCell.selectedImage.isHidden == true{
           currentCell.selectedImage.isHidden = false

       }
       else{
          currentCell.selectedImage.isHidden = true
       }
    }

    }

}
```

For single selection you can use isSelected in your collectionviewcell class as follow:

```
 override var isSelected: Bool{
   didSet{
     if self.isSelected
     {
     //This block will be executed whenever the cell’s   selection state is set to true (i.e For the selected cell)
     }
    else
     {
     //This block will be executed whenever the cell’s selection state is set to false (i.e For the rest of the cells)
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to highlight collection view cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4932718873, blue: 0.4739984274, alpha: 1)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the borders thick enough to cover the entire cell

Code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    addToList.append(objectsArray[indexPath.row])
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 200.0
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.4).cgColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ternary operator

```
  override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                            self.backgroundColor = self.isSelected ? .systemGray4 : .systemGray6
                        }
                    }
                }
```